Endpoint timeout when accessing endpoint in ASP.NET Webforms
I need to retrieve a JWT token from a web service for further communication with their party. I can access the endpoint through Postman/console application, yet I can't do the same inside a Webforms project.
I could have posted some code but class TokenManager is the same in both projects.
Reducing it to a simple:
protected async void BtnGetToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TokenManager tokenManager = new TokenManager();
    LblToken.Text = await tokenManager.GetTokenAsync();
}

returns this error:

I checked it with some IT admins and the root cause can be a reverse-proxy in the way.

When you say it works via Postman and console, are those apps running on the same machine that the Web Forms app is hosted on?

Also, the code shown in your error images clearly isn't the same code shown in the question. Are you sure you've shown us the correct thing?

@mason Yes they're running from the same machine but as i said, they said it might be some issue with the reverse proxy. Yes you're right about the second comment! That was another thing I tried that yielded no results either

Turns out due to the web proxy i had to include in the web.config file the following:
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy autoDetect="True"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>

